# Live Agent "update" tag

Tags: liveagent, pre-chat

In prechat Form I am passing the "emailID check" then want to update the related FirstName or LastName in case it is different.

Do we have any tag such as "liveagent.prechat.update:Contact", I have used it but it is not updating the Contact Name.
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not have such tag. You can accomplish  this using the console toolkit, once the chat is accepted, you can get the chat details using the console toolkit and update the records. You could also do this from the pre-chat page using an Ajax call. Either way, this is an odd requirement.

Comment: Can't we use findOrCreate.map method to update field values on records.

Comment: @sfdcrowdy No, you will need console toolkit + vf remoting